# Virtual PDF printer with customizable options

Tags: pdf, printing, printer

I am looking for something that lets me install a shared printer on my users and when they print they should be shown an options dialog whose options would get passed to the virtual printer.

The virtual printer would then do some actions depending on the options marked.

The type of options I want to handle are basically a dropdown to select an overlay to put on the PDF (letterhead). Another dropdown to choose where the generated PDF should be stored: user folder, upload to intranet site, store on Google Drive.

I have many letterheads so having one virtual printer for every letterhead is out of the question, not to mention all combinations of letterhead+output are too many.

Of course, if it's open source software it'd be awesome!

thanks,
marc

Comment: found this by googleing http://fineprint.com/pdftutorial/using-letterhead/ it's commercial.

Comment: Thanks but that won't let me automate things, I want a printer so I can apply the letterhead, log the print jobs, store it somewhere to know who printer what etc.

Comment: You might need to write one using ghostscript. Not sure though.

Comment: Google Cloud Printer will put PDF's in Google Drive and some other options.  Most word processors have templates.  Each letterhead could be a template you apply inside the word processor before you print. Just an idea.

Comment: cybernard, that's what we are doing now but means a) one template per letterhead (or a macro) and b) everything must go trhough the word processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@marc.fargas you are looking for Print&Share ( http://www.printandshare.info ).
It allows you to insert overlays, select profiles based on recognition, use dynamic ranges (with formulas), customize the document etc..
Far more advanced compared to fineprint.

You can have multiple outputs (= a different channel) this allows you to store the same output (with different customizations or pages selected) on a network share, ftp, SharePoint or other DMS.

I've followed some of these basic videos to get started: http://www.printandshare.info/learn.html